# React Download Json File from Controller

Tags: reactjs, json, .net, download

I have a react app that contacts a backend dotnet controller to download various types of files.  When I download most files everything works fine and the files are correct.  When I download a json file, the file contains only `[object Object]`. Below is the code in the call method.

```
  public downloadFile = async (fileId: number) => {
    const response = await HttpUtility.postFileDownload<any>(DOWNLOAD_URL + fileId, {})

    let fileName = response.headers['content-disposition'].split('filename=')[1].split('\'')[2]

    if (fileName === undefined) {
      fileName = `file-id-${fileId}-${moment().format()}`
    }

    fileDownload(response.data, fileName, response.headers['content-type'])
  }
```

When, I look at the dev tools in Chrome, the response looks correct. Any pointers on what I need to do to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

This May works

```
fileDownload(JSON.stringify(response.data), fileName, response.headers['content-type'])
```

Comment: Thanks.  Thant worked.